# Xamarin.iOS can't build project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I can't build my xamarin ios project. In the morning, it's was fine. But now, when I'm trying to run or build my project nothing happens. I haven't change anything. I have found this in output log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: AlarmButton.Touch, Configuration: Debug iPhone ------
1>  Generated session id: f301fb763b459ef8426c2556b278a6cf
1>  Generated build app name: AlarmButtonTouch
1>  Connecting to Mac server XamarinMac.local...
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(996,3): error : 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**EDIT:**
It works fine if I'm using iPhoneSimulator, but still doesn't work on real iPhone

**UPDATE:**
There is detailed log:

```
1>Task "ACTool" (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:SessionId=f301fb763b459ef8426c2556b278a6cf (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:AppManifest=Info.plist (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      ImageAssets=
1>          Resources\ImageSet.xcassets\AppIcons.appiconset\Contents.json
1>                  InProject=false
1>          Resources\ImageSet.xcassets\confirmedButton.imageset\btn_alert_green.png
1>                  InProject=false
1>          Resources\ImageSet.xcassets\confirmedButton.imageset\Contents.json
1>                  InProject=false
1>          Resources\ImageSet.xcassets\ic_tab_indicator.imageset\Contents.json
1>                  InProject=false
1>          Resources\ImageSet.xcassets\ic_tab_indicator.imageset\ios_tab_selected.png
1>                  InProject=false
1>          Resources\ImageSet.xcassets\ic_tab_indicator.imageset\ios_tab_selected_3x.png
1>                  InProject=false
1>          Resources\ImageSet.xcassets\LaunchImages.launchimage\Contents.json
1>                  InProject=false
1>          Resources\ios_tab_selected.xcassets\AppIcons.appiconset\Contents.json
1>                  InProject=false
1>          Resources\ios_tab_selected.xcassets\Images.imageset\Contents.json
1>                  InProject=false
1>          Resources\ios_tab_selected.xcassets\Images.imageset\ios_tab_selected@2x.png
1>                  InProject=false
1>          Resources\ios_tab_selected.xcassets\Images.imageset\ios_tab_selected@3x.png
1>                  InProject=false
1>          Resources\ios_tab_selected.xcassets\LaunchImages.launchimage\Contents.json
1>                  InProject=false (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:OptimizePNGs=True (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:OutputPath=bin\iPhone\Debug\ (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:IntermediateOutputPath=obj\iPhone\Debug\ (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:ProjectDir=C:\Users\prisiazhnyi.v\Source\Repos\alarmbutton-bors\AlarmButton\AlarmButton.Touch (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:ResourcePrefix=Resources (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:SdkDevPath=\Applications\Xcode.app\Contents\Developer (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:SdkBinPath=\Applications\Xcode.app\Contents\Developer\Platforms\iPhoneOS.platform\Developer\usr\bin (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:SdkUsrPath=\Applications\Xcode.app\Contents\Developer\Platforms\iPhoneOS.platform\Developer\usr (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:SdkPlatform=iPhoneOS (TaskId:13)
1>  Task Parameter:SdkVersion=9.3 (TaskId:13)
1>  ACTool: 2016-05-11T10:02:49.7373919+03:00 - Started (TaskId:13)
1>  ACTool: 2016-05-11T10:02:49.7434050+03:00 - Initializing (TaskId:13)
1>  ACTool: 2016-05-11T10:02:49.7434050+03:00 - Initialized (TaskId:13)
1>  ACTool: 2016-05-11T10:02:49.7459115+03:00 - Determining the modified files that should be copied to the mac (12 files) (TaskId:13)
1>  ACTool: 2016-05-11T10:02:49.7654640+03:00 - Serializing intputs (TaskId:13)
1>  ACTool: 2016-05-11T10:02:49.7749915+03:00 - Executing (TaskId:13)
1>  ACTool: 2016-05-11T10:02:50.8513713+03:00 - Logging messages (TaskId:13)
1>  ACTool Task (TaskId:13)
1>    AppManifest: Info.plist (TaskId:13)
1>    DeviceModel: <null> (TaskId:13)
1>    DeviceOSVersion: <null> (TaskId:13)
1>    ImageAssets: (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ImageSet.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/Contents.json (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ImageSet.xcassets/confirmedButton.imageset/btn_alert_green.png (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ImageSet.xcassets/confirmedButton.imageset/Contents.json (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ImageSet.xcassets/ic_tab_indicator.imageset/Contents.json (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ImageSet.xcassets/ic_tab_indicator.imageset/ios_tab_selected.png (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ImageSet.xcassets/ic_tab_indicator.imageset/ios_tab_selected_3x.png (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ImageSet.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage/Contents.json (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ios_tab_selected.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/Contents.json (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ios_tab_selected.xcassets/Images.imageset/Contents.json (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ios_tab_selected.xcassets/Images.imageset/ios_tab_selected@2x.png (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ios_tab_selected.xcassets/Images.imageset/ios_tab_selected@3x.png (TaskId:13)
1>      Resources/ios_tab_selected.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage/Contents.json (TaskId:13)
1>    IntermediateOutputPath: obj/iPhone/Debug/ (TaskId:13)
1>    OptimizePNGs: True (TaskId:13)
1>    OutputPath: bin/iPhone/Debug/ (TaskId:13)
1>    ProjectDir: C:/Users/prisiazhnyi.v/Source/Repos/alarmbutton-bors/AlarmButton/AlarmButton.Touch (TaskId:13)
1>    ResourcePrefix: Resources (TaskId:13)
1>    SdkBinPath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin (TaskId:13)
1>    SdkPlatform: iPhoneOS (TaskId:13)
1>    SdkVersion: 9.3 (TaskId:13)
1>  Tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool execution started with arguments: --errors --warnings --notices --output-format xml1 --output-partial-info-plist /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/AlarmButtonTouch/f301fb763b459ef8426c2556b278a6cf/obj/iPhone/Debug/actool/partial-info.plist --launch-image LaunchImages --compress-pngs --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 8.3 --platform iphoneos --compile /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/AlarmButtonTouch/f301fb763b459ef8426c2556b278a6cf/obj/iPhone/Debug/actool/bundle /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/AlarmButtonTouch/f301fb763b459ef8426c2556b278a6cf/Resources/ImageSet.xcassets /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/AlarmButtonTouch/f301fb763b459ef8426c2556b278a6cf/Resources/ios_tab_selected.xcassets (TaskId:13)
1>  Tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool execution finished (exit code = 1). (TaskId:13)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(996,3): error : 
1>  ACTool: 2016-05-11T10:02:50.8513713+03:00 - Finished (TaskId:13)
1>  Output Item(s): FileWrites= (TaskId:13)
1>  Output Item(s): FileWrites= (TaskId:13)
1>  Output Item(s): FileWrites= (TaskId:13)
1>  Output Item(s): _PartialAppManifest= (TaskId:13)
1>  Output Item(s): _BundleResourceWithLogicalName= (TaskId:13)
1>  Output Item(s): _ACTool_PartialAppManifest= (TaskId:13)
1>  Output Item(s): _ACTool_BundleResources= (TaskId:13)
1>Done executing task "ACTool" -- FAILED. (TaskId:13)
1>Done building target "_CoreCompileImageAssets" in project "AlarmButton.Touch.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:19)
```

**SOLUTION:**
Okey. I have deleted imageassets in my .csproj file and it works fine right now.

Comment: Need more information about the error. It could be anything from a provisioning to unintentional link stripping.

Comment: To see more information you should increase build output verbosity in visual studio preferences. ("Projects and Solutions" -> "Build And Run")

Comment: Answer your own question